# How to split a string on a range?

Tags: c++, stl

I'd like to know how to split a string on a range:

```
std::string = "some<foo>some<bar>some...";
```

Need to get a range between <...>:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  What do you want to happen to  the `some`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string::find` repeatedly:

```
size_t pos = 0;
while (true) {
    size_t strt = mystring.find('<', pos);
    pos = mystring.find('>', strt+1);
    if (strt == string::npos || pos == string::npos) break;
    cout << mystring.substr(strt+1, pos-strt-1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Was there a reason `pos` is not local to the loop but `strt` is?

Comment: @SethCarnegie you need to preserve `pos` for the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thx! Is there a way to implement it using an iterator?

Comment: Yes, you can build an iterator around this code: pos would store the current state, ++ and -- would run one iteration of the loop, and you would need a variable to store the last substring. You could also push back the strings into a vector, and use vector's iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Using iterator:

```
string str = "some<foo>some<bar>some";

string::iterator i = str.begin(), token = i;

while (i != str.end()) {
    if(*i == '<') {
        token = i+1;
    }
    else if (*i == '>') {
        string item(token, i);
        cout << item << endl;
    }
    i++;
}
```